# What does a sentence like "Little if......but...." mean?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

I've read it in a news report, "**Little if** any news will be released during the event(China reform summit), **but** official news agency Xinhua traditionally issues a dispatch on the last day."

Well, I guess I know what every character means, but I still don't get the idea.
The whole report: http://www.aljazeera.com/news/asia-pacific/2013/11/china-communist-party-kicks-off-reform-summit-201311983528568573.html
The sentence is in the forth paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it means is:

'Little news will be released during the event, indeed there may not be any released at all, until.....'

All that is abbreviated to '**Little, if any**, news will be released during the event, until....'

The phrase 'little, if any' is very widely used in English, especially at the start of sentences.